# How to avoid being blocked when conducting craigslist search

Tags: javascript, php, http

New to HTTP so not sure if this is a dummy question...I am trying to implement some simple search functionality for CL and collect simple search results. Reading some old threads, it seems this is likely to be blocked by CL since they are very sensitive to scraper operations.

I've implemented something using PHP at server side which is functional, but possibly blocked, can we do it at client side?

Specifically, instead of doing HTTP request from server side (with a fixed IP likely to be blocked), I am wondering if I can have the HTTP request sent from the client side, and all data processing done by javascript at client side, so that each time the IP address for HTTP request will be different according to client. CL cannot block such application.

Thanks,
Jia

Comment: Learn about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: `CL cannot block such application` - of course it can, if the blocking is done to avoid too many requests from a single "referrer" - besides that, as previously mentioned, you'll probably run into `same origin` or `CORS` issues if you try doing something CL doesn't want you to do

Comment: use tampermonkey to make the request from a browser by navigating pages: works every time.

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks a lot for your comments. learned a new thing about "HTTP referrer":) this is from wiki:  The HTML5 standard added support for the attribute/value rel="noreferrer", which instructs the user agent to not send a referrer.

Another referrer hiding method is to convert the original link URL to a Data URI scheme-based URL containing small HTML page with a meta refresh to the original URL... not sure if those techniques work...